# direct complement

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification, vector-spaces, vectors

Can you please check if my solution is correct?
I need to find a direct complement to
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{U} = \{(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4) \in \mathbb{R}^4\,|\, x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4 = 0\,,~ x_1+x_2-x_4 = 0\}
\end{align*}
and describe it by its basis.

What i have done:
My basis for $\mathbb{U}$ is $(-1, 1, 0, 0)$, $(-1, 0, 2, 1)$.
(I expressed $x_1$ and $x_3$ as they are leading variables in RREF of matrix $ \begin{pmatrix}1&1&1&1\\1&1&0&-1\end{pmatrix} $). Then I extended the basis and got the answer : $(-1, 1, 0, 0), (-1, 0, 2, 1), (1, 0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 1, 0)$.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  [Here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference/27793#27793) is a MathJax tutorial.  $(-1,0,2,1)\not\in U$

Comment: @ J.W.Tanner can you please explain what am i doing wrong?

Comment: Did you mean $(-1,0,2,\color{red}-1)?\;$  The sum of the components must be $0$ to be in $U$

Answer (score 1):

First of all you have to find a basis of $\mathbb{U}$. To do this, simply solve the following system of linear equations:

\begin{cases}
      x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 = 0\\
      x_1 + x_2 - x_4 = 0
    \end{cases}

I will leave the details to you. The general answer is

\begin{pmatrix}
w - t\\
t\\
-2w\\
w\\
\end{pmatrix}

with $t,w \in \mathbb{R}$ arbitrary. A basis of the space where this general vector lives might be $\{(1, 0, -2, 1), \ (-1, 1, 0, 0)\}$.

Now, because $\mathbb{U}$ is a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^4$, we have that $\mathbb{U} \oplus \mathbb{U}^\perp = V$. So, if we find two vectors that are perpendicular to our basis, that are also linearly independent, then we have found what we are looking for. Two vectors that satisfy this are $\{(0, 0, 1, 2), \ (1, 1, 0, -1)\}$

The problem with the two vectors you proposed is that $\mathbb{W} \cap \mathbb{U} \neq \{0\}$, where $\mathbb{W} = \langle (1, 0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 1, 0) \rangle$. That means that it is not a direct complement, whereas it is the case when $\mathbb{W} = \mathbb{U}^\perp$. Probably the reason why you got confused is because it is indeed true that your proposed extended basis spans $\mathbb{R}^4$.

Comment: "tonetillo4 sorry, why is it {(1,0,−2,1), (−1,1,0,0)}?(basis)  i got the general answer same as you wrote. can you explain please

Comment: First of all, check that both vectors are in $\mathbb{U}$. As J. W. Tanner pointed out, $(-1,0,2,1)$ is not in $\mathbb{U}$. Then, the coefficient matrix (the one you wrote in the question) has a rank of 2. That means that the solution to the system of equations is a space of dimension 2, which implies that $\mathbb{U}$ has two basis vectors. Finally, $\{ (1,0,-2,1),(-1,1,0,0) \}$ is linearly independent. This all leads to the fact that $\{ (1,0,-2,1),(-1,1,0,0) \}$ must span $\mathbb{U}$.